# Is it possible to convert Lapis Lazuli into usefull stuff with EE3?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-equivalent-exchange

I'm playing Tekkit Lite with Equivalent Exchange 3, so I'm lacking any EMC values on my items and only can convert using the given recipes and the usage of Minium Stone. Additionally, there are over 30-50 stacks of lapis lazuli in my chests that are totally unused. Is there a way of changing dyes into others or something to convert Lapis Lazuli into Iron/Wood or sth like that?

Comment: "there are over 30-50 stacks of lapis lazuli in my chests that are totally unused"  At least convert it into blocks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert dyes into other dyes, however, it is not possible to convert anything to or from bonemeal or lapis, as this is considered an exploit. For a complete list of transmutations, go into NEI and look up the uses for the minium stone. If it isn't on that list, then it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

EE is being remade to make it less OP This means there's going to be No Condensers or Relays Collectors and stuff. You get a minium stone to make some stuff but not a lot. This is making the game a bit more fair so people know what there doing. Check NEI for the recipes. I think Pressing R while hovering over a item in NEI will show you what can be made with that item.